# Properties and ref

Tags: c#, properties, ref

Consider class `A` with private field `_data` of any type (eg. `int`) and property `Data` to work with that field:

```
public class A
{
    private int _data;

    public int Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => _data = value;
    }

    // Constructor is redudant, I created that for testing purposes...
    public A(int data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
}
```

Now consider class `B` with the same private field `_data` and property `Data` that only returns reference to our field:

```
public class B
{
    private int _data;

    public ref int Data
    {
        get => ref _data;
    }

    // Constructor is redudant, I created that for testing purposes...
    public B(int data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
}
```

And now the question for which I can't find the answer: Why I'm able to change the value of `_data` in the instance of class `B` if there is no `set` modifier for `Data`?

```
B b = new B(50);

// This line doesn't produce any warnings or errors
b.Data = 100;

Console.WriteLine(b.Data == 100); // True
```

Does that work like *pointers* in C/C++ and compiler understands that this property is just a *pointer*, so it automatically assings value to what this pointer point to (without any special operators and/or casting) or I'm missing something?

I couldn't find an answer on this on `learn.microsoft.com` (searching both for `Properties` and `ref`), so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do whatever* you want to `_data`. You don't need a property with a setter to modify a private field in the same class.

Comment: _data has no knowledge of Data. They're both totally separate ints. A property would be used to control access to the private field outside of the class, but inside you can do anything to _data (like @BrootsWaymb said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, using ref we get a reference and we can change the value.

Considering this code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.Data = 100;
b.Data = 200;
```

The IL generated code is:

```
// A a = new A();
IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApp.A::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0

// B b = new B();
IL_0007: newobj instance void ConsoleApp.B::.ctor()
IL_000c: stloc.1

// a.Data = 100;
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: ldc.i4.s 100
IL_0010: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp.A::set_Data(int32)

// b.Data = 200;
IL_0016: ldloc.1
IL_0017: callvirt instance int32& ConsoleApp.B::get_Data()
IL_001c: ldc.i4 200
IL_0021: stind.i4
```

- Using the setter, we call a method, and pass the `int32 value` as a parameter.
- Using the by ref getter, we got the reference, to an integer here : `int32&`.

**Properties having a getter by ref can't have a setter, says the compiler.**

*Because it is useless and redundant.*

Thus, a treatment can only be done in a by ref getter, for example to return one or the other reference according to certain conditions:

> `CurrentColor` of a control that is `Enabled` will returns `ColorEnabled`, else `ColorDisabled`.

---

The native x86 machine code transcribed for `a.Data = 100` is:

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+40h]  
mov         edx,64h  
cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
call        00007FF7E93B0568
```

For `b.Data = 200` is:

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+38h]  
cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
call        00007FF7E93B0580  
mov         qword ptr [rbp+20h],rax  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+20h]  
mov         dword ptr [rax],0C8h
```

Comment: I would add that the other important thing is the use of the `stdind.i4`, that means `store indirect i4`, that for a C programmer means something like `*ptr = 200`

Comment: [OpCodes.Stind_I4 Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stind_i4)

Comment: That was indeed very good explained, thank you! :)